# Reverse url is not working in Django 1.6 inside middleware

Tags: django, django-urls

`reverse('settings:force_update')`, this one is working in other places. But while trying to use it in one of the middleware. It saying that settings namespace is not defined.

And for this `reverse('force_update')` No reverse found.

```
class UserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.get_full_path().endswith('/settings/force/') \
            and request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous() \
            and request.institute.force_student_data and not request.user.is_data_collected(request.institute):
            return redirect(reverse('settings:force_update'))

        return None
```

Comment: Can you add the `middleware` class here. You might need to use `reverse_lazy`  depending on the case.

Comment: I have added the middleware code @fxgx